# Java Serialization with Transient Field

Tags: java, serialization, transient

With Java Serialization, I understand that when a field is marked as transient, it is not serialized. So when the object is deserialized, what happens to the fields that were set to
transient? Do they get set to the values defined in the constructor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They get set to the default value for the type: zero, false, or null.